# ASP .Net MVC 5 How to create list in Create View? One to many relation in EntityFramework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to be able to have list for my model which in Create view could be edited. It would be one to many relation. For example:
If I had Client model with possibility of creating shopping list for this person, but list would has it's properties too :

```
public class Client 
{
public int ClientID {get; set}
public string Name {get; set;}
public virtual ICollection<Product> Product {get; set;}
}

public class Product 
{
public int ProductID {get; set;}
public int ClientID {get; set;}
public string ProductName {get; set;}
public string Description {get; set;}
public virtual Client Client {get; set;}
}
```

In create view for Client I want to give him name and be able to add products without any limit and after I would have Client with list of products - save him.
And of course then I want to be able to view Client with list of products in Details view.

What would be the best approach for this? Please advise :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is the entity framework and the codefirst method, which I introduced in the example below.
Only I made a small change in the Client class and changed the `Product` to `Products`.

```
public class Client 
{
   public Client()
   {
      Products = new List<Product>();
   }
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public virtual ICollection<Product> Products {get; set;}
}
```

Add Data In DataBase

```
Client client = new Client();
client.Name = "Client 1";


Product product1 = new Product() { Description = "desc 1", ProductName = "product 1" };
Product product2 = new Product() { Description = "desc 2", ProductName = "product 2" };
Product product3 = new Product() { Description = "desc 3", ProductName = "product 3" };

client.Products.Add(product1);
client.Products.Add(product2);
client.Products.Add(product3);
db.Clients.Add(client);
db.SaveChanges();
```

**Real Example**

> Just me in this example add the data to the controller in the database which you have to do in the Repository layer.

Your Model

```
public class Client
{
   [Key]
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
   [Key]
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string ProductName { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
   public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
}
```

Tour Context

```
class yourContextName : DbContext
{
     public yourContextName() : base("yourConnectionName")
     {
     }

    
     protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
     {
         base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
         modelBuilder.Entity<Client>().Property(c => c.ID)
        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
         modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().Property(c => c.ID)
        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
     }
     public DbSet<Client> Clients
     {
         get;
         set;
     }

     public DbSet<Product> Products
     {
         get;
         set;
     }
}
```

Your Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AddProduct()
{
    var client = new Client();
    client.Name = "Client 1";
    return View(client);
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddProduct(Client client, string[] ProductNames, string[] Descriptions)
{
    client.Products = new List<Product>();
    for(int i=0;i<ProductNames.Length;i++)
    {
         if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ProductNames[i]))
         {
             Product product = new Product() { Description = 
             Descriptions[i], ProductName = ProductNames[i] };
             client.Products.Add(product);
         }
     }
    //add data to database
    db.Clients.Add(client);
    db.SaveChanges();

    
    return View(client);
}
```

Your View

```
@model StackOverFlowMVC.Controllers.Client

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AddProduct";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>AddProduct</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddProduct", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myform" }))
{
    <label>Client Name : </label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
    <br />
    <hr />
    <br />
    <div id="prItems">
        <section id="row1" num="1">
            <div style="margin:10px;">
                <label>Product Name 1 : </label>
                @Html.TextBox("ProductNames",null)
            </div>
            <div style="margin:10px;">
                <label>Product Descr 1 : </label>
                @Html.TextBox("Descriptions", null)
            </div>
            <input type="button" class="RowDelete" value="-" onclick="removeRow(1)" />
            <hr />
        </section>
    </div>
    <button id="btnAddRow">Add Product</button>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="btnsubmit" />
}

@section scripts{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#ProductNames').val('');
            $('#Descriptions').val('');
        });
        $('#btnAddRow').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var row = "<section><div style = 'margin:10px;'><label></label><input type='text'></div><div style='margin:10px;'><label></label><input type='text'></div><input type='button' class='RowDelete' value='-'/><hr /></section>";
            $('#prItems').append(row);
            orderRow();
        })


        function removeRow(num) {
            $('#prItems section').each(function (idx) {
                if ($(this).attr('num') == num) {
                    $(this).remove();
                }
            });
            orderRow();
        }
        function orderRow() {
            var rowCount = $('#prItems section').length;
            if (rowCount > 0) {
                $('#prItems section').each(function (idx) {
                    var num = idx + 1;
                    $(this).attr('id', 'row' + num);
                    $(this).attr('num', num);

                    $(this).children().children().nextAll().slice(0, 1).prev().text('Product Name ' + num + " : ");
                    $(this).children().children().nextAll().slice(0, 1).attr('name', 'ProductNames');


                    $(this).children().next().children().nextAll().slice(0, 1).prev().text('Product Descr ' + num + " : ");
                    $(this).children().next().children().nextAll().slice(0, 1).attr('name', 'Descriptions');

                
                    $(this).children().next().next().slice(0, 1).attr('onclick', 'removeRow(' + num + ')');
                });
            }
        }
    </script>
}
```

Comment: In the solution you have provided you have specified that there will be 5 products. I want this to be flexible, maybe input and next to it plus button which would add new product and clear input so I could add another product. Is it possible?

Comment: You can create dynamic fields with JavaScript or jQuery and send the information to the action according to the same pattern. I imported 5 products to clarify the concept.

Comment: You have to manage all the activities. Anything can be done

Comment: Do you have any examples, posts, which would help me do this?

Comment: see this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66119810/dynamic-row-numbering-using-javascript

Comment: That works almost perfectly but I am getting error while saving - Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Project'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Project'. The duplicate key value is (0). The statement has been terminated. - can you check my github project github.com/IzaGorska/OnBoardingApp - the ralation Client - Product in my case is Project - Step

Comment: Add an ID field to the Client and Product classes and set the Identity value to Ture in Sql.

Comment: What does to set Identity value to Ture mean?

Comment: Also could you modify this, so after clicking add it wouldn't add another input but clear this one and the product would be added to list below?

Comment: Identity : Creates a unique identifier for each record in sql through which it can be identified

Comment: It adds a set of controls to the list with each click, and you can delete them again. Did you test the code?

Comment: I did test it and adding steps works but saving project does not, i am having exception I mentioned before. Can you guide me how to change identity value so it would work?

Comment: This is about sql. What technology do you use to communicate with the database?

Comment: Entity framework and I have data in localdb

Comment: see this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I did, and everything looks just as in my project but it doesn't save, see yourself -> https://github.com/IzaGorska/OnBoardingApp

Comment: Wrong in Project class [DatabaseGenerated (DatabaseGeneratedOption.none)] ProjectID
 i changed to  [DatabaseGenerated (DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] ProjectID

Comment: I changed that and yet still net project doesn't save in db.

Comment: I sent you the complete answer. No more help has been made by me.

Comment: Okey thank you very much anyway. I'll try to figure out why it doesn't save

Comment: Let me also say the last point. In the create view, you entered the action name incorrectly in the post method. The name of the action sent is create. I explained the rest.

Comment: You are right, i have used Index instead of Create, now I have new problem to resolve. Thank you again for all the help.